# How can I stop Apt from marking packages as manual when you run the "apt install <package which is already there>" command?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

How can I stop Apt from marking packages as manual when you run the "apt install " command?

For example, Accidentally, when I run `apt install <package-which-is-already-there>` (**of a package which is already there**), it marks the package as `manually installed`.

Which I hate a lot. How can I stop apt from doing this? It even messes up things sometimes.

Comment: Keep in mind that this mechanism has a reason: if package `X` has been automatically installed as a dependency of package `A`, it will be removed when you remove `A` and run `apt autoremove`. If you need `X` and don't mark it as manually installed, you implicitly rely on `A` being installed.

Comment: Try to avoid "accidentally" running apt commands. Take a moment to ask apt what you have installed. Test the consequences of your proposed change before commanding apt to do something perhaps foolish. Apt is not intelligent -- it will try very hard to obey your command, regardless of your actual intent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aside from the remedy provided by @user535733, you can always check before installing what the apt will do by simulating the install using the `-s` flag:

```
apt install -s <package-which-is-already-there>
```

If the package is already installed you will get a line like this:

```
<package-which-is-already-there> is already the newest version (<version>).
```

From the man page `man apt-get`:

```
-s, --simulate, --just-print, --dry-run, --recon, --no-act
   No action; perform a simulation of events that would occur based on the
   current system state but do not actually change the system. Locking will be
   disabled (Debug::NoLocking) so the system state could change while apt-get
   is running. Simulations can also be executed by non-root users which might
   not have read access to all apt configuration distorting the simulation. A
   notice expressing this warning is also shown by default for non-root users
   (APT::Get::Show-User-Simulation-Note). Configuration Item:
   APT::Get::Simulate.

   Simulated runs print out a series of lines, each representing a dpkg
   operation: configure (Conf), remove (Remv) or unpack (Inst). Square brackets
   indicate broken packages, and empty square brackets indicate breaks that are
   of no consequence (rare).
```

Comment: This solves my issue :) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

The default of apt is to mark a package *that you specified* as `manual`. You specified it -- that's the definition of 'manual'.

You can override this behavior by using the `--mark-auto` option in your apt command. (Ubuntu 22.04 and newer)

```
sudo apt install --mark-auto <package-name-1> <package-name-2> ... <package-name-n>
```

If you forget to use `--mark-auto`, and some of your packages are changed to `manual`, it's trivial to change apt-marking back from `manual` to `auto`:

```
sudo apt-mark auto <package-name-1> <package-name-2> ... <package-name-n>
```

Comment: Actually `apt-get` has `--mark-auto` option in Ubuntu 22.04. However, you might not want to change the status to auto if the package which was already there was marked manual.

Comment: @jarno thank you! Big edit to include your welcome contribution.